# Spring @Transactional and long-running business logic

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am having some problems with Spring @Transactional and hope to find a solution here. I have a method in the service labeled as @Transactional which works by calling a method to request data via HTTP protocol (I'm using Apache HttpClient now), parsing the response and writing the result to the database. Since it all works in one method I'm afraid that this may cause transaction cancellation, because my project has a transaction time limit and request from external API may be really long.

Here I would like an answer on how to most correctly separate HTTP request+response parsing and database operations in such a case. As an option it is possible to have two methods one for transaction and the other for the rest of the logic, but I already have an assumption that there is a generally accepted design pattern for such tasks.

Comment: The only options are doing the HTTP request outside of the transaction boundary, or use the `TransactionTemplate` instead of the annotation to limit the span of the transaction as much as possible

Answer (score 2):

Different types of I/O in single @Tranactional method could cause trouble. If the API call responds very slowly for a while, this method would hold the borrowed Connection while waiting for the response.

You must break the single method.

1. Method1 will make the rest call. Response received with http status code 200 OK. Store it in suitable collection.
2. Method 2 will process records from method 1. You can explore on TransactionTemplate.

Refer - [Sample code for reference](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/jdbc/spring-transaction-management-example-with-jdbc-example/), [Sample code here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-programmatic-transaction-management)